# ArangoDB and user-defined functions or stored procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, user-defined-functions, arangodb, foxx

ArangoDB documentation (Foxx section) says:

> Because Foxx runs directly inside of ArangoDB it lets you bundle all the database queries and logic necessary to handle a request in one place.

Is there any additional way, 'more native', than using the 'Foxx framework' to implement something equivalent to user-defined functions or stored procedures in ArangoDB?

Answer (score 4):

you can use [user defined functions](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/extending.html) which can be used inside of AQL.

UDFs have a clear limited scope of just working with the data you put into them via parameters. So UDFs have a narower scope than stored procedures - you can't run sub-queries in them.

While Foxx can offer more functionality than stored procedures (you can directly talk to it via RESTful HTTP) its what represents stored procedures in ArangoDB.

Comment: I don't know the history, but nowadays one can access the data in the database, so it is not the case that UDFs can only work "with the data you put into them via parameters".

Comment: Hi, I can assure you that while it may not instantly break, its not supported.