# Does Arangodb support stored query?

Tags: sql, arangodb

For example, I have Node Collection A and Links Collection B

I would like for each elements of A, add a new properties depend on the number of links it has from B
This operation will run every day once.

Normally, in RDBM such as MySQL, I would use stored query for it.
Is something of equivalent can be done in ArangoDb?

Comment: Should have search more thoroughly before:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110281/arangodb-and-user-defined-functions-or-stored-procedures

Comment: You could also write a small script for arangosh and run it like `arangosh  --javascript.execute script.js`

Answer (score 0):

Currently ArangoDB doesn't offer [prepared statements, but some users want it](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/6999). 
If you're interested too, subscribe that github issue by giving it a thumbs up.